# Mongoose update middleware - need to create hooks for every single update middleware?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Let's say I have the following schema:

```
PersonSchema = {
    name: String,
    timesUpdated: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    }
}
```

Every time that the given person is updated, I would want the `timesUpdated` field to increment by one. Now, I could use Mongoose's `update` middleware hook, which would be called by something like

`PersonModel.update({_id: <id>}, {name: 'new name'})`

and my `timesUpdated` field would be appropriately incremented. However, if I only wrote a hook for the `update` middleware, the following code would *not* update my `timesUpdated` field:

`PersonModel.updateOne({_id: <id>}, {name: 'new name'})`

In order for my count to be updated, I would have to write middleware for the `udpateOne` query. This pattern repeats for several other similar middleware hooks, such as `updateMany`, `replaceOne`, `save` (if you want to update a document this way), `findOneAndUpdate` and I'm sure many others.

I use the example of an updated count for simplicity, but I could also have used an example where some other unrelated action happens upon changing my name. Am I missing something in how hooks should be used, or is this a limitation of mongoose hooks?

Answer (score 3):

Pre save hook will only be executed with following functions according to mongoose's middleware [document](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html).

- init
- validate
- save
- remove

However update functions are working directly with MongoDB, therefor there is no general use hook applies on all update functions. See related discussion on [Github](http://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/964).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a function to perform your task before/after all required calls (to update or updateOne) rather a hook, because of the limitations mentioned in the other answer and the question.

Or perhaps limit the kinds of methods that can be called to the ones that have the hook set.

Or use a hook which will always get called in the middle-ware sequence, like a validate hook.